# Maximize the number of permutations living in certain subset of $n\times n$

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, permutations, bipartite-graphs, permanent

For $\alpha\in\{1,\dots,n\}^n$ let ${\cal M}_\alpha$ be the class of matrices $M\in\{0,1\}^n$ which contain exactly $\alpha(i)$ times $1$ in the $i$th line.

Now I want to know which matrices $M\in{\cal M}_\alpha$ maximize the following score: $$|\{\sigma\in{\cal S}_n:\forall i.M_{i,\sigma(i)}=1\}|$$

Are there any results pointing in that direction?

[EDIT] User [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof) just pointed out that if we let ${\cal G}_\alpha$ be the class of (bipartite) graphs with vertex set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ and edges only between $v$s and $w$s such that $v_i$ has degree $\alpha(i)$ then we are asking for graphs $G\in{\cal G}_\alpha$ which maximize the number of perfect matchings.

Comment: Perhaps graph-theory or bipartite-graph or extremal-graph-theory would be a good tag. The question is about maximizing the number of perfect matchings in a bipartite graph, given the degree sequence for one side of the bipartition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your matrices are binary, your score equals to their [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Permanents_of_.280.2C1.29_matrices) and an upper bound for it is given by
[Bregman-Minc inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman%E2%80%93Minc_inequality).

Comment: Thank you, this is a very helpful hint.